# "Mock" Docker secret in Python app while developing?

Tags: python, docker

I have a Python app which is meant to run as a Docker container. As the app uses crendential data I've put these into a Docker secret. The app reads the secret from `/run/secrets/my_secret`. This works perfectly fine when running the app in a container.

```
with open("/run/secrets/my_secret", "r") as my_secret_file:
    foo(my_secret_file.read())
my_secret_file.close()
```

However for developing and testing the app locally I don't want to rebuild and restart the Docker image each time I added or changed code. But when just running it without Docker it understandably cannot load `/run/secrets/my_secret`.

Is there some mechanism in Python (Pycharm) or Docker I could use?

Comment: If you create a local folder /run/secrets and have your my_secret_file available, then when you run your app locally not in the docker container, it should work file. /run/secrets is located at the docker level not at your local.